# Command Prompt/Powershell: What Command to Open a non-text file with a Text Editor?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface

How do I open a non-text file, say server.js, with a text editor (e.g. Notepad) with a command prompt?

I currently use a workaround where I create server.txt, edit it, then rename it to server.js, but it'd be nice to have a more straightforward method.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a file which does not have .txt extension in notepad, try

> c:\> notepad server.js

Note: You can start also start Visual Studio Code, using commandline with `> code <filename>`. If the file does not exist, a new file will be created in editor.

Comment: Nice! Ty. Now is there a command that can both create and open the item? `new-item abc.yaml | notepad abc.yaml` works, but is there anything faster?

Comment: just - notepad <filename> will do, if the file does not exist, notepad will prompt to create a new file

Comment: this is awesome, tysm